# XNA framework and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: windows-8

Can I develop XNA based application for Windows8 in Visual Studio 2012?How can I make metro based  app utilizing XNA framework?

Comment: You can't develop Modern UI applications using the XNA Framework, they are two, entirely different .nET Profiles ( WinRT ) and the ( XNA )

Answer (score 1):

XNA Game Studio has been discontinued by Microsoft, but [Monogame](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame) is starting to really take off! Monogame can deploy to Windows, Windows Store, Mac, Linux, and mobile platforms as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try these visual studio XNA extensions, they work for VS2010, VS2012 and VS2013:

https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases

(Just download the latest release and follow the instructions that come with the package)